# NgMap throwing error of Unknown provider: NgMapProvider <- NgMap

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-map

I am using ngMap but it is throwing error. I check everything. Every thing is mentioned. I am using this in two places in my application . In one place it is working but not in the second place. Both are at different file location.

[image: ngMap Error]

Comment: Add a plunker here.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add `ng-map` as a dependency in one of your modules (you talked about two different places, on different files):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);
```

This error is shown whenever Angular couldn't inject some service - if no service of name `ngMap` is registered, it will check if a provider (conventionally named `ngMapProvider`) is too. If not, then, you'll see the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have yo check if :

1. You have `ngMap` src in your lib folder
2. You have added the dependency
3. You have added the ngMap.js to your index.html

Comment: Thanks for the help